# What are interlocking table legs like this called?

Tags: construction, table, desk, bench

For temporary support of a glass pane, I have been looking for cheap steel rods bent
into this simple upside-down U shape (the bottom two points will contact the ground):

[image: U-Shaped piece]

The idea is to join a few of these pieces together by the legs (keeping the rods hinged together with a short plastic tube that has double the diameter of the steel rods or,
instead, with two zip ties to act as a tube) and form some "angular" squarish/triangular
path (from the top view, not the side view used for the figure above) for standing
stability.

For example, I want to place 3 of these U pieces together to form 4 ground contact points
(two abutting legs are considered to have just one shared contact point here) which are
the corners of a square.  The top will then consist of 3 horizontal bars (3 sides of a
square) on which I can set the glass pane.

[image]

Of course, this construction style could be generalized to other interlocking shapes
similar to the U above.  Shortening the rightmost leg in the figure above to form just
a J should be enough to interlock with the next J.  A manufacturer could even combine
the "short plastic tube" for hinging the legs with the U/J piece, so that a full standing
frame can be formed from copies of just one easy-to-carry rigid piece.  In the end, I would
prefer this interlocking piece to be plastic (like PVC), not steel, which makes this
manufacturing even easier and cheaper.

So, does this construction style have a name?  The obvious Google searches like
"interlocking table legs" did not help me, but I would guess this is commonly done
somewhere.  Where can I find interlocking pieces already designed to form the standing
structure I want?  In case this is all a silly idea, how would you support a glass
pane temporarily if you didn't want it to touch the ground?  (Honestly, even for
permanent support, e.g., a glass desk or table, this seems like a fine idea if
we just somehow prevent the glass from sliding off and prevent the ground contact
points from getting bumped into a straight line.)

Comment: Maybe it's just the medications I'm on right now, but I had a _very_ hard time following your text description. You provided a nice image of a U-shaped leg, how about a drawing of how you'd connect one or more of these together. Are you looking to _buy_ such a pre-built contraption or are you looking to make it yourself? If you're looking to make it yourself, what it's called is kinda irrelevant...

Comment: @FreeMan Ok, I added one image for the square/cube example I described (black is the U pieces, red is the sleeves to hold the legs together; sleeves need to be somewhat longer than I have drawn them to keep the legs rigidly parallel with each other).

Comment: @FreeMan As for your question, I'd like to just walk into Home Depot and find interlocking PVC pieces somewhere.

Comment: @FreeMan One key feature of this interlockability that might be understated above is that the top-view angle of the interlock is adjustable, so I could form a square one day, a hexagon the next day, a zigzag the next day...I didn't explain it, but I have reasons for changing that top-view shape often.  Whatever I choose, it's structurally strong enough to support a layer above it (and I can repeat this whole process to form more layers).  Judging by the lack of answers here, I guess I should just build it from scratch with the steel rods and sleeves to demonstrate it better.

Comment: @FreeMan By the way, I can also close the polygons (e.g., adding one more U piece and two more sleeves to the square drawn above).

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that type of table leg construction doesn't have a name. Mostly based on the fact that I've never seen anything like that. I doubt you're going to find pre-fab connectors like that outside of some furniture kit that already has a set of legs that's designed to do exactly what you're trying to do. If you do find such a furniture kit, I'm 99.999% certain that these leg sleeve hinge pieces will be bespoke for that particular kit and only available as replacement parts from that manufacturer.

Comment: I'm sure that several of us could come up with several different ways of making such a connector, but that's not what you've asked for here.

Comment: For temporary support, this seems like a lot of hassle and cost vs setting screwing a few 2x4s together

Comment: @whatsisname All right, so how would you screw the 2x4s together exactly?  An internet reference is fine.  In addition to it being slower and more of a hassle, I think it will be weaker unless your structure is much heavier.  I honestly can't think of any advantage, so I wish someone could start the comparison process by giving an answer like this, even if their solution is just for a square/cube support structure.

Comment: @bobuhito unless your glass is made of [Degenerate matter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter) some 2x4s will be plenty rigid enough. Hold them up together and put some deck screws in to hold them together. It's really not that complicated.

Comment: They also make sawhorses with 2x4 shaped slots so you can connect 2 with 2 2x4s for holding sheet goods and stuff. Just get two of those if screwing like together is somehow too challenging.

Comment: @whatsisname Sawhorses are bulkier than what I'm proposing, you know.

Comment: @bobuhito so? Your only listed requirement is for temporary support. Why is a slightly larger stand a deal breaker? What other requirements are there you haven't included?